# Magento 2 order quantities by groups of 4

Tags: grouped-products, b2b

I want to make a B2B wholesale website in M2 and my question is if there is a way (by default or extension) so a registered customer can order items by groups of 4,16, etc.
For example, if the product was batteries, the customer should be able to order 4,16,etc. because they come in packs - he can't order eg. 5 batteries (a 4pack and a single battery...)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a technical or code related issue, you can just add battery pack as product instead single battery and update the price and other things respectively.